# Ocultar WebMethod en el navegador

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webservice

Estoy creando una aplicacion web con `C#`, `ASP.NET`, `AJAX` y `JavaScript`, estoy usando un `WebService` y todo funciona bien, el problema es que subí la aplicación al servidor para hacer pruebas y al abrir la consola del navegador (F12 Google Chrome) me di cuenta que aparecen todos mis `WebMethod` en los cuales a veces envío parámetros especiales (`IdUsuario`, `password`, `email` del usuario) y otros que no es necesario que vea nadie mas.

Mi pregunta es si existe una manera de que mis `WebMethod` no sean visibles en ningún navegador. En esta imagen se puede apreciar de qué hablo:

[image: Problema]

Comment: No puedes ocultar un servicio que supuestamente expones para que pueda se consumido. Si el problema es como envias las credenciales quizas eso es lo que debas cambiar, quizas enviar los datos encriptados

Comment: Entonces los metodos web siempre seran visibles cierto? Vere de que manera encriptar los parametros entonces

Comment: es que el webmethod es algo que expones como contrato, no tendria sentido ocultar algo que expones para ser consumido

Answer (score -1):

Bueno, primero que todo, eso no se puede esconder, pues necesitas que sean visibles para que sean consumibles. Ahora bien, lo que puedes hacer es intentar protegerlos, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa720571(v=vs.71).aspx) te dejo un artículo de Proteger servicios Web XML creados mediante ASP.NET. Aquí también dejo un par de métodos ([Primero](http://revistadigital.inesem.es/nuevas-tecnologias/seguridad-en-c-encriptar-y-desencriptar-datos/), [Segundo](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)) simple para encriptar información.